# symfony3 Assetic cssrewrite создает не верный путь

Tags: css, symfony3, background, css-filters, assetic

```
{% stylesheets
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/fonts/*'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/custom.css'
    filter='cssrewrite'%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

это линки css

```
.topblock div:first-child{
    background: url('../images/subsbg.jpg') no-repeat center top;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
 }
```

это класс в custom.css
В итоге путь на сайте пытается такой выдать

```
 /Resources/public/images/subsbg.jpg
```

там фото конечно же нет. Как правильно работать с Assetic в данном случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог официальный мануал. css нельзя линковать через @AppBundle. только через bundle/